# Can the Asus TF700 run ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-for-android

So i'm thinking of getting the Asus Transformer Infinity TF700 and I was wondering if it could run ubuntu.

Also I have heard that there are not many good apps for tablet android OS, if I did get ubuntu would it have more apps? What other benefits does ubuntu have over android?

Comment: Is this page accurate? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/tf700t if it is does that mean i should wait a bit before getting ubuntu on the tablet?

Comment: Yes, that page is accurate. Currently, Ubuntu Touch is released as a developer preview version that can be run on Google Nexus devices. Other people took the liberty to port it to other devices, such as your TF700T, and that is what that page is for. So yes, it is accurate. You should not install it because it does not replace your Android. For more information, see the answer to this this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/339996/i-need-help-with-my-ubuntu-touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Long story short*: if you can live without rotation; or not knowing if you will have sound, video codification or Suspend/resume capabilities; or some other minor glitches go ahead, otherwise, look for another table.

*Details*

Following the table [State of Things](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/tf700t#State_of_things) (updated till 2013-05-03) this is the actual status of the tablet:

```
Graphics          Perfect
Boot process      Working          -- No boot animation
Rotation          Bloked/Broken    -- General issue: not supported in Ubuntu Touch yet.
Wireless network  Work in Progress -- OK, but can't enter password with on-screen keyboard
Sound             Unknown          -- No details
Touch             Perfect
Camera            Working          -- Not working zoom & face camera
Video Decode      Unknown          -- No details
Suspend/Resume    Unknown          -- No details
Dock keyboard     Work in Progress -- Special keys not working, on input shell restarted sometimes
Dock touchpad     Unknown          -- No cursor in the shell
Dock Battery      Working          -- No dock battery indicator
```

Legend:

- **Perfect**: Work without problems.
- **Working**: Works, minor issues only, some patches pending.
- **Work in progress**: Self-explanatory
- **Bloked/Broken**: Severely broken, unusable or progress is blocked
- **Unknown**: Unknown status

Comment: It will be fixed in the future though right? So I could get the tablet and get ubuntu on it later when it's fixed?

Comment: I don't know, I will never know, those that know are the developers themself, I'm just providing the information available.