# I need help with my Ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

so I flashed and everything was well but after tinkering a while I ran across some problems 
first off a lot of my settings don't work, some of the apps don't either for ex the camera app just goes to a white screen. and the computer doesn't recognize it.
its a nexus 4 and I'm running Ubuntu on my laptop. not sure if its a bad flash, I tried to download the update but it keeps failing.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of Ubuntu Touch (the Ubuntu operating system for phones and tablets) is a Developer Preview. This tells you two things:

- **Developer** tells us that this version of Ubuntu Touch is meant for developers; the people that will create applications for it.
- **Preview** tells us that it is not "complete", it's just a preview of the features.

Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview does **not** provide all the features of a traditional phone, and a **lot** of settings and applications will not work. It is **not** meant to replace your current Android operating system.

- See this page: **[Ubuntu Wiki - Touch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/)** for more information. This page also has links on who to contact if you want technical discussions.
- For more information on how to install Ubuntu Touch, see this page: **[Ubuntu Wiki - Touch Install](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install)**.
- For more information on which devices Ubuntu Touch is currently supported on, see this question: **[What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-the-ubuntu-touch-support)**